# UITableViewCell button and segmented control

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a segmented control for people and animals. Segment 1 loads people, segment 2 loads animals.

Inside every cell i have an add button, that should add people and animals respectively.

```
@objc func addPerson(_ sender: UIButton){
    let buttonTag = sender.tag
    let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: someTableView as UIView)
    let indexPath: IndexPath! = someTableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
    let object = peopleArray[indexPath.row]
      print(“person added“)
}


@objc func addAnimal(_ sender: UIButton){
    let buttonTag = sender.tag
    let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: someTableView as UIView)
    let indexPath: IndexPath! = someTableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
    let object = animalsArray[indexPath.row]
    print(“animal added”)

}

func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = someTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: “SomeTableViewCell") as? SomeTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        let object = peopleArray[indexPath.row]


        cell.configureCell(//load some data)
        cell.add.tag=2
        cell.add.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.addPerson(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


    case 1:
        let object = animalsArray[indexPath.row]


       cell.configureCell(//some details)
        cell.add.tag=3
        cell.add.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.addAnimal(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    default:
        break
    }


    return cell

}

 @IBAction func segmentedTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    someTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Inside the UITableViewCell i have set the add button as follows

```
@IBOutlet weak var add:UIButton!
```

When the view loads and I press add on a person it prints "person added",

if i tap on animals segmented control it loads the animals and if i tap add on an animal it prints “person added“ “animal added”

if i go back to people and press add on person it prints “person added“ “animal added”.

Why is this happening? Desired behaviour is when the add inside a person cell is tapped to print "person added" and when the add inside an animal is tapped to print "animal added"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as Matt mentioned i wasn't removing the target-action pairs.

One solution is to avoid having two functions that link to one button and print one statement each, i now have one function linking to one button. Depending on what the button's tag the function it will print the respective statement.

```
 @objc func add(_ sender: UIButton){
 switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        print("person added")

    case 1:
        print("animal added")

    default:
        break;
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
guard let cell = someTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: “SomeTableViewCell") as? SomeTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
case 0:
    let object = peopleArray[indexPath.row]


    cell.configureCell(//load some data)
    cell.add.tag=0
    cell.add.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.add(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


case 1:
    let object = animalsArray[indexPath.row]


   cell.configureCell(//some details)
    cell.add.tag=1
    cell.add.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.add(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

default:
    break
}


return cell

}

@IBAction func segmentedTapped(_ sender: Any) {
someTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening?

Because *you* are *making* it happen.

Keep in mind that cells are reused. So this `add` button may have existed in a previously used cell. In your `cellForRowAt`, you are saying `cell.add.addTarget(action:for:)` without removing any *existing* target-action pairs that `add` may *already* have. So you just keep piling up target-action pairs for the `add` button. So clicking the `add` button does all of them.

Basically your entire architecture is undesirable. You would do better to have two different cell types distinguished by two different reuse identifiers, so that cells used for animals do not get reused for people. But even then you must be careful not to add the same target-action pair twice (or more), since that would cause the button press to call your action method twice (or more).

Comment: 1. How would i remove the existing target action. 2. I get what you are saying... In this instance i define the cell inside every case, but i at the top what do i give to the cell? or is it irrelevant?

Comment: I answered the question, namely why you are seeing the phenomena you are seeing. I'm not going to write the fixed code for you. That's your job. If you don't understand how a control's target-action dispatch table works, do some research! Start here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol

Answer (score 0):

The way you tried is wrong as it will always give you tag 0 and 1. so this is perfect way  to do it
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

  @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

  var peopleArray = ["Mark", "Lee", "John", "Bang", "Mich"]
  var animalArray = ["cat", "Dog", "cow", "rat", "Tiger"]


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return peopleArray.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tvc", for: indexPath) as! tvc
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
    case 0:
      let object = peopleArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.label.text = object
        //cell.del.tag = 0
      cell.del.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.del.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.add(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


    case 1:
      let object = animalArray[indexPath.row]


        cell.label.text = object
        //cell.del.tag = 1
      cell.del.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.del.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.add(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        default:
      break
    }


    return cell

  }

  @IBAction func segmentedTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    tableview.reloadData()
  }

  @objc func add(_ sender: UIButton){
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
    case 0:
      print("person added:\(peopleArray[sender.tag])")

    case 1:
      print("animal added:\(animalArray[sender.tag])")

    default:
      break;
    }

  }





}


class tvc: UITableViewCell{
  @IBOutlet weak var del: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```